# Htaccess www to non-www but keep the url intact

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I think that this is rather simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

I have a domain like https://www.example.com

I want to rewrite it to https://example.com

That works. But I am also rewriting other urls like https://www.example.com/privacy

If I try to rewrite these too the user is always redirected to https://example.com/privacy.php

How do I prevent my server to show the actual filename instead of its rewritten url?

My code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^checkout checkout.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^imprint imprint.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^terms terms.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^allergy allergy.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^nutrition nutrition.php [L] 

RewriteRule ^order/([A-Z]*)?$ confirmation.php?lang=&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Ok, so you mean url https://example.com/privacy.php is getting displayed in browser as a redirection? Because I can't see any of the Rules which could do that, kindly confirm the same once.

Comment: Hey, yes. The file is named privacy.php. But internally, I don't link to privacy.php but /privacy. So let's say you navigate to www.example.com/privacy: The url in the browser changes to example.com/privacy.php instead of example.com/privacy. Hope this makes the situation clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(checkout|imprint|privacy|terms|allergy|nutrition)/?$ $1.php [L] 

RewriteRule ^order/([a-z]+)/?$ confirmation.php?lang=&id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Make sure to test after clearing your browser cache. Problem appears to be due to your patterns not using end anchor.

I have combined your multiple similar rules into one rule.

Comment: Hey, thanks fpr you answer. However, I still get redirected to .php . It is removing the www. but always appends .php at the end (showing the filename instead of path). I cleared my cache but still no luck. It seems to work with the order page however. So www.example.com/order/SHDJS successfully redirects to example.com/order/SHDJS

Comment: Check updated answer. You probably need to add `Options -MultiViews` and do try in a new browser or remove old cache completely.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick ;) Have a nice day!

Comment: Ok, that was too early :D The problem is that it also removes the endings of images thus making them disappear. Any way to keep them untouched?

Comment: `it also removes the endings of images` - It is not happening in my suggested rules. You can see there is no such rule there. Can you give example of your image URL and the exact error you're getting while fetching an image?

Comment: It's working fine, my bad. Have a great day